# java.net.Socket blocks to timeout if you read too soon after write

Tags: java, sockets

Weird behavior with Java sockets code running on Java 7 on an AWS machine:

I have a custom protocol to my server wherein we open a socket, then send and receive BSON messages.  The test client creates and opens a socket, sends a request, and then camps on the the socket's InputStream, waiting for the response.  When a response is received or when the read times out, the next request is sent.

I've discovered that if I touch the socket's `InputStream` too quickly after I'm done sending the request through the `OutputStream`, the socket will occasionally block until its read timeout.  I've tried both `socket.getInputStream().read(...)` and `socket.getInputStream().available();` both calls cause the problem.  If I simply wait 200ms or so after sending, I get nearly 100% successful reads from the server.  If, on systems on the same subnet, if I touch the socket immediately after the write (`socket.getOutputStream().write(...);` `socket.getOutputStream().flush()`), the socket blocks until its 20-second timeout is reached for between 1% and 7% of all attempts.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  Do you know what's causing it? Do you have a suggestion on how to deal with it? I expect most reads to come back in between 20 and 40ms on a fast network (they mostly do, except the ones which block and time out).

The actual code in use is pretty complex, but here's some relevant snippets:

High-level read/write:

```
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
String req = getRequestData();

String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
protocolHandler.write(uuid, getUsername(), os, req);

long dt = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
if (dt < 125l) {
    try { Thread.sleep(125-dt); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
}

String in = protocolHandler.read(uuid, is, timer, getResponseCount(), getTimeout());
```

Socket creation:

```
private Socket newSocket(String socketKey) {
    Socket con = null;

    try {
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(getServer(), getPort());
        con = new Socket();
        con.setKeepAlive(true);
        if (getPropertyAsString(SO_LINGER,"").length() > 0){
            con.setSoLinger(true, getSoLinger());
        }
        con.connect(sockaddr, getConnectTimeout());
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Created new connection " + con); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        Client client = new Client(con);
        Client.threadIdToClientMap.put(socketKey, client);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        log.warn("Unknown host for " + getLabel(), e);//$NON-NLS-1$
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn("Could not create socket for " + getLabel(), e); //$NON-NLS-1$
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return null;
    }

    // (re-)Define connection params - Bug 50977 
    try {
        con.setSoTimeout(getTimeout());
        con.setTcpNoDelay(getNoDelay());
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        log.warn("Could not set timeout or nodelay for " + getLabel(), se); //$NON-NLS-1$
        se.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

    return con;
}
```

Socket write:

```
public void write(String messageId, String playerId, OutputStream os, String hexEncodedBinary) throws IOException {
    String messageHexBytes = substituteVariables(hexEncodedBinary);

    AbstractMessage messageObject = MessageRewriter.parseRequestData(messageHexBytes);
    int seq = MessageRewriter.getSequence(messageHexBytes);

    messageObject.setPassthrough(messageId);
    byte[] messageBytes = MessageRewriter.serialize(seq, messageObject);

    os.write(messageBytes);
    os.flush();
}
```

Socket read:

```
public String read(String messageId, InputStream socket, LatencyTimer latencyTimer, int requiredResponseCount, int socketTimeoutMillis) 
        throws ReadException {
    String threadName = "thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId();

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("passthrough "+messageId+"\n");
    int nBytesThisRead = -1;
    byte[] buffer=null;
    try {
        int nResponses = 0;

        // As long as we have bytes or need a response, continue to produce messages.  Messages we don't use will be cached.
        // The socket object throws an exception on timeout (20 seconds-ish) to terminate on "nothing read".
        //
        // TODO: refactor this abortion so it's readable and understandable
        //
        while ((! interrupted) && (nResponses < requiredResponseCount || socket.available() > 0)) {
            // clear "buffer" to make log messages less confusing (because on 0-byte reads, residual data is logged if we don't do this)
            buffer = new byte[0];

            // read the size bytes
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] sizeBuffer = new byte[4];
            while (totalBytesRead < BYTES_PER_INTEGER) {
                try {
                    nBytesThisRead = socket.read(sizeBuffer, totalBytesRead, BYTES_PER_INTEGER-totalBytesRead);
                    if (nBytesThisRead > 0) {
                        latencyTimer.stop()
                        totalBytesRead += nBytesThisRead;
                    }
                }
                //
                // this is the timeout we get ~5% of the time if I don't wait ~ 100ms
                //
                catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    log.error(threadName+" timeout waiting for size bytes");
                    latencyTimer.stop();
                    return "";
                }
            }

            int messageSize = getLittleEndianInteger(sizeBuffer);
            log.debug(threadName+": message size: " + messageSize);

            buffer = Arrays.copyOf(sizeBuffer, BYTES_PER_INTEGER+messageSize);

            // reset; now read the message body
            totalBytesRead = 0;
            while (totalBytesRead < messageSize) {
                nBytesThisRead = socket.read(buffer, BYTES_PER_INTEGER+totalBytesRead, messageSize-totalBytesRead);
                if (nBytesThisRead > 0)
                    totalBytesRead += nBytesThisRead;
            }

            if (totalBytesRead != messageSize) {
                log.error(String.format("%s abandoning attempt to read %d responses for id %s. Read %d bytes; needed %d.", 
                        threadName, requiredResponseCount, messageId, totalBytesRead, messageSize));
                throw new ReadException(
                        "Unable to read complete Gluon message.", null, result.toString()+toHex(buffer, BYTES_PER_INTEGER + nBytesThisRead));
            }

            message = MessageRewriter.deserialize(buffer);
            String hexString = toHex(buffer, BYTES_PER_INTEGER + messageSize);
            String uuid = message.getPassthrough();

            if (messageId.equals(uuid)) {
                ++nResponses;
            }
            else {
                log.debug(String.format("Read: %s message type %s with msgId %s to cache", 
                        threadName, message.getClass().getSimpleName(), uuid));
                messageCache.put(uuid, new MessageToClient(message, hexString));
            }

            // even ignored messages get sent to the verifiers
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(String.format("Read message for %s (%d bytes): %s", uuid, BYTES_PER_INTEGER + messageSize, hexString));
                log.debug(String.format("%s Read: message type %s with msgId %s from socket; still need %d response messages.", 
                        threadName, message.getClass().getSimpleName(), messageId, requiredResponseCount-nResponses));
            }
            result.append(hexString);
            result.append("\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: clear out the socket? We'd need a new "open new socket" checkbox in the UI, and fail-fast when unchecked.
        String msg = result.toString()+"partial:"+toHex(buffer, BYTES_PER_INTEGER + nBytesThisRead);
        log.error(threadName+" throwing read exception; read message so far is:\n"+msg,e);
        throw new ReadException("Unable to read expected result.", e, msg);
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Whatever the causes of this may be, they lie in your application. Certainly not because of 'touching' the input stream 'too soon'.

Comment: That is undoubtedly true.  Something I'm setting, or not setting, or doing to the socket is undoubtedly the problem.  I simply have no clue what it might be.  It's remarkable that simply adding a Thread.sleep(125) makes the problem go away, though.

Comment: @JerryAndrews Would you mind adding some code to the question, it might make it a bit easier for us to help.

Comment: as requested. :)  I should've done that anyway.  I removed a lot of logging, to make things more readable in this format.

Comment: One more detail that might or might not be relevant: if I run the client on my Mac to a server running on an EC2 instance (Amazon Web Services (AWS)), it works 100% of the time without inserting delays.  If I run the client on an EC2 instance on the same subnet as the server, the delay is required.

Comment: In your read-methode the size of the sizeBuffer should also be BYTES_PER_INTEGER. If you are trying to read integer values from the socket, maybe you can try using a DataInpustream with readInt(). Also try it without the "socket.available()" condition.

Comment: Good points; thanks Hector.  I need the socket.available() condition--not all received messages increment nResponses, and I want to flush the socket. The decoded message's messageId has to match the supplied messageId. Messages which don't match can be unrequested notifications.  The timeout always occurs while waiting on the length bytes, and I never get a partial read on those if the first one arrives.

Comment: The buffer size is not relevant, just thought i should mention it. In java an integer is always 4bytes, so you dont need to specify a constant i guess. Glad you found the problem.

Comment: Wish I had found the problem. Still a complete mystery.  BYTES_PER_INTEGER comes from the protocol definition, not the Java definition. It's very convenient that they're both "4".  :)

Comment: Additional data: java.lang.Socket's InputStream doesn't always obey the read(...) contract; I have observed a state change in some sockets wherein, after several message exchanges on the socket, read returns with 0 bytes read, when 4 are requested, instead of blocking as documented.